# Update Oracle table with values from another table

Tags: oracle11g

I have two tables ORDERS and ORDER_TEMP and both are identical in structure. ORDER_ID is the primary key in both the tables.

Now, I have to Update KEY_ID column in ORDER table from the value from ORDER_TEMP table.

There are over million records in both the tables.

```
UPDATE ORDER  
SET KEY_ID = ( SELECT KEY_ID FROM ORDER_TEMP WHERE  ORDER_TEMP.ORDER_ID = ORDER.ORDER_ID and ORDER_TEMP.PNP_GROUP=99)
```

If i put a where clause in on the ORDER table and run it for one order it did work but when I did for the entire table it was running forever and it didn't work.

Please help

Comment: Does "didn't work" mean that there was an error?  Or that you simply got tired of waiting for the query to finish?  If there was no error and this is simply a query performance issue, what is the query plan?  What index(es) are available?  How long did you wait for the query to run before giving up?  What fraction of the rows in the `ORDER` table are you updating?

Comment: It took more than 45 minutes and was still processing before I gave up. I am trying to update 200,000 records in Order table. Indexes are in place for both the tables.

Comment: What is the query plan?  What indexes are available?  Are there any triggers defined on the `ORDER` table?  Since you have no `WHERE` clause, your query would update every row in the `ORDER` table-- I assume what you are saying is that you really want to update fewer than 20% of the rows, right?  As written, your `UPDATE` statement will set `KEY_ID` to `NULL` for any row in `ORDER` where there is no matching row in `ORDER_TEMP`.  I assume that is not what you are hoping for?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your intention is to update only those rows in the `ORDER` table where there is a match in the `ORDER_TEMP` table and where the `KEY_ID` is different, and ignoring the fact that `ORDER` is an invalid table name, I would start with ensuring that you only update the fewer than 20% of the rows in the table that you expect to modify

```
UPDATE ORDER  
   SET KEY_ID = ( SELECT KEY_ID 
                    FROM ORDER_TEMP 
                   WHERE ORDER_TEMP.ORDER_ID = ORDER.ORDER_ID 
                     and ORDER_TEMP.PNP_GROUP=99) 
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM order_temp
                WHERE ORDER_TEMP.ORDER_ID = ORDER.ORDER_ID 
                  and ORDER_TEMP.PNP_GROUP=99
                  and order_temp.key_id != order.key_id)
```

If `KEY_ID` can be `NULL` in either table, you'd need to adjust the inequality comparison in the `EXISTS` clause.

If that doesn't resolve the problem, we'll need more information starting with the current query plan and the indexes that are available.

Comment: This a good start, but we really do need more information to make sure we give the correct answer.,  It would be preferable to not have two columns in the sub query, since even you will only select on 1 index, then be forced to search the second from the result of the 1st index which will slow things down.